# How to make plotly python not automatically download graph when open html?

Tags: python, html, graph, visualization, plotly

I am using plotly python to do some heat like maps. I am doing this all offline. The code generates a html page which shows the graph, but once the html file is opened it also downloads a png form of it. (This can get annoying, every time I open the html it downloads another copy). So how do I stop it from downloading every time the html is opened?

```
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


layout = go.Layout(
        title = 'Muse',
        xaxis=dict(
            title='xaxis',
            titlefont=dict(
                family='Courier New, monospace',
                size = 18,
                color ='#7f7f7f'
                )
         ),
        yaxis=dict(
            title='y',
            titlefont=dict(
                family='Courier New, monospace',
                size = 18,
                color ='#7f7f7f'
            )
        )
) 

data = [
        go.Heatmap(
            z=[[1, 20, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, -10, 200]],zmin=-500,zmax=500,
            x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']
            )
        ]

fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
offline.plot(fig, filename='labelled-heatmap.html', image="png",auto_open=False)
```

Comment: The data is obviously meaningless, the point is to convey the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML file downloads the image either every time or never. If you remove `image=png`, opening the HTML file will not automatically trigger a download.